# How to get height of the working area of the screen on Android

Tags: android, height, screen

I am writing a reading application on Android. To separate the text on pages I must get a height of screen of application, without status bars. How to do this?

Comment: You should always consider giving as much of the information you have tried (code, links or other information) to help know exactly what you are asking for and trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
int width=getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int height=getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

gives screen width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but in android you can get the height of any subClass of View so you can simply [`find your main View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29) and [`getHeight`()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getHeight%28%29) (get its height).

in any case you should try to be **a lot** more specific then this if you want people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Option one:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
```

then, in your use case:

```
var screenWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
var screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

or simply use:

```
var height = view.measuredHeight
var width = view.measuredWidth
```

if you do it inside of an Activity, then remove the "view."

The second option is better, because it considers the rotations of your device.